# I want to call a function several times without the use of a For loop in Matlab

Tags: matlab, function, vectorization

Actually, I want to call a function several times without the use of a For loop in order to vectorize my program.

My program is:

```
for k=3:(floor(size(Uarray,1)/length(w)))   
%      k  = 3:(floor(size(Uarray,1) / length(w)));
       U1 = Uarray((((k-1) * length(w)+1) : k * length(w)),:);
       Ut = MatrixProduct(Ut,U1);       
end
```

`Uarray` is a variable matrix of 2 dimensions and its elements are numbers.

It is defined as `Uarray=[];` and it could be 144*20 or another value.

If we assume that `Uarray` has 144 columns and 20 rows, this means that for each column, we have a matrix 12*12, but in row form. Also, if we say that `w=linspace(0, 1e15, 5)` means that each group of 5 correspond to 5 different matrices and the next group to another 5 matrices, but in row form.

The idea is to multiply the `Uarray` with `w` with the `Uarray` the next group, that is `2w+1`, `Uarray` with `w+1` with `2w+2`. The program is working good. But, I dont have idea about vectorization and optimization in matlab.

**In my case, I want to know if I can call a function several times without use of for or loops.**

Comment: you need to rephrase the question, add details and try to provide a minimal code of a for loop that works. For example what is the size of Uarray? is it a cell array or doubles? saying "each column is a matrix" is very condusing to read.

Comment: Thanks Troy, Uarray is a variable matrix of 2 dimensions and its elements are numbers and it could be 144*20 or another value. if Uarray has 144 columns and 20 rows, this means that for each column, we have a matrix 12*12, but in row form. Also, if  we say that w=linspace(0, 1e15, 5) means that each group of 5 correspond to 5 different matrices and the next group to another 5 matrices. The idea is multiply the Uarray with w with the Uarray the next group, that is 2w+1, Uarray with  w+1 with 2w+2.I want to know if I can call a function several times without use of for or loops.

Comment: @user3375311 Curious if this is still needed?